# Slow Ubuntu SSH login

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, configuration-files

I installed a box with Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is fine, but when I connect through SSH the password prompt and the login completion take many seconds.

What could be the cause?

I installed many times Ubuntu, but this is the first time I find this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the resolution path here:

[ask ubuntu] https://askubuntu.com/questions/246323/why-does-sshs-password-prompt-take-so-long-to-appear?newreg=b1eddc1d91c846d8900b6555d39e26e7

In my case the issue was due the fact that the server has no fully qualified domain name, so I had to add:

```
UseDNS no
```

to /etc/ssh/sshd_config, connecting as root and restarting ssh.

In this way the system avoids to wait for reverse DNS lookup timeout and the login sequence is done promptly.